# Gatsby: How to solve tslint expects component to receive props when it comes from a query into the component itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, gatsby, contentful

I use Gatsby with Typescript to create a blog based on Contentful CMS.

I have `FeaturedPost` component which I want to put in the main page and this is the code:

**FeaturedPost.tsx**

```
interface IProps {
  data: {
    contentfulPost: ContentfulPost;
  };
}

const FeaturedPost: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ data }) => {
  const { title, description } = data.contentfulPost;
  return (
    <>
      <Header>{title}</Header>;
      <div>{description}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query featuredPost($slug: String) {
    contentfulPost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      slug
      description {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default FeaturedPost;
```

This is my index page code:

**index.tsx**

```
const IndexPage: React.FunctionComponent<P> = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO
        title="Home"
        keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]}
        description="Index for something I can't remember?!"
      />
      <FeaturedPost />
      <h1>Hi people</h1>
      <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
      <p>Now go build something great.</p>
      <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Tslint now expects that I pass a prop called `data` to `FeaturedPost` component since I implement `interface IProps` on `FeaturedPost`, but actually there is no `data` to get passed.

`FeaturedPost` itself receives it as a response from the sent query. Do you have any idea what's wrong with this code or how can I satisfy the linter?

Comment: Which version of Gatsby are you using? AFAIK, graphQL query in non-page component will be ignored, you'd have to use [StaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/) instead. Since it use render props, it'll give you an easier time typing it as well

Comment: I'm using gatsby v2

Yes, I have missed this part. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool! let me add an example as an answer, might be helpful for other folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gatsby v2, graphql queries in non-page components will be ignored. [Use StaticQuery instead](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/). Here's a small example:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StaticQuery, graphql, Link } from 'gatsby'

type TOCDataType = {
  readonly allSitePage: {
    edges: [
      {
        node: {
          id: string
          path: string
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

const TableOfContents: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SitePageQuery {
        allSitePage {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={(data: TOCDataType) => (
      <div>
        {data.allSitePage.edges.map(({ node }) => (
          <li key={node.id}>
            <Link to={node.path}>{node.path}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  />
)

export default TableOfContents
```

Comment: Just a little comment, `React.SFC` is now deprecated and replaced with `React.FunctionComponent`